# Does anyone know how to get the name according to a rule_number in JDT's parser

Tags: compiler-construction, eclipse-jdt

I know how to get a name of terminal token. figure terminal  token name , it's  simple that `terminal_token = name[terminal_index[token_kind]]`.

How to figure a non_terminal name with  non_terminal_index.

I need some help.

Answer (score 2):

I think i fond the answer here  [generateParser.](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/howto/generate%20parser/generateParser.html)
I think the answer is that

```
int index = Parser::lhs[rule_number];
int name_index = Parser::non_terminal_index[index];
char[] _name =  Parser::name[name_index];
```